# Should I keep the random distribution object instance or can I always recreate it?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I have this code:

```
static std::mt19937 rnd;

// ...

static uint32_t rndInt(uint32_t min, uint32_t max) {
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t>(min,max)(rnd);
}
```

Is that good practice or should I store the `uniform_int_distribution`?

Comment: c.f. [Use std::uniform_int_distribution and define its range later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328948/use-stduniform-int-distribution-and-define-its-range-later) for info on changing the range `param` later on the same instance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt that the distribution object is expensive to create and destroy, although I suppose it might do slightly more than just store the parameters `min,max`. It might precalculate some useful values based on the parameters, for instance in the obvious implementation `2**32 % (max-min+1)` is the number of different values from the generator that would be discarded and re-tried.

In principle, a distribution object is allowed to store inside it some bits of entropy that were drawn from the generator on a previous call to `operator()`, but not needed. Those bits could be used for a later `operator()` invocation. So if `min==0` and `max==1`, then you can get 32 calls to `operator()` on the distribution per call on the generator. That's what the `reset()` function is about, to clear this state.

So if you use the same min/max values repeatedly, then technically you're wasting random bits by using a new distribution each time -- you could perhaps end up with fewer calls to the engine than if you kept the distribution object around. But I doubt it matters, especially since MT is fast.

Comment: Hehe, yea, mostly what I thought but good to hear it from someone else.

Comment: Btw., not sure (didn't checked), but if this class is header-only anyway, I would expect that there is probably no overhead at all as it would be all inlined.

Comment: @Albert: depends on your definition of "no overhead", I suppose. Even if the con/destructor are inlined, they still have to actually execute. You can imagine that some distribution requires a complicated set-up procedure based on the parameters before it's ready to use, it's just that `uniform_int_distribution` clearly doesn't.

Comment: See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14858040/259795, where it is suggested that constantly resetting a distribution object (similar to recreating it) could potentially affect the distribution of the generated numbers, depending on how it is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do the following:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> distrib(16, 97);
```

Then you may call `distrib(rnd)` multiple times without regenerating the distribution each time.

The way you are performing the operation forces the distribution to be recreated each time you make the call.  If your min and max params are fixed, then create a distribution object and call it, otherwise, stay with what you have.

BTW, I would seed `rnd`, using `time(NULL)` or some other seed method.

Comment: `time` is a notoriously bad seed due to its determinism and typical granularity of 1 second. Seeding with one call to `std::random_device{}()` is far preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy is stored in `std::mt19937` which means that you will continue the random sequence, but as noted by Steve Jessop it still has some overhead for creating an object. If you expect this function to be called frequently with the same arguments, then you can cache `std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t>` objects in a map that uses `std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>` as a key.

Comment: I would expect that this approach with the map is actually more overhead. :)

Comment: I would agree here. Then you will just need to follow codewiz51's advice.