# Use std::uniform_int_distribution and define its range later

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have problem where I want to create a `std::uniform_int_distribution` in a struct and then give its range later. Below is what I want.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

struct group_s {
   int k;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
} group;


int main()
{  
    group.dis(0,19);
    std::cout << group.dis(gen) << ' ';
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
no match for call to '(std::uniform_int_distribution<>) (int, int)'
  cpu_group.dis(0,19);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Unlikely. The error does not match your code. Also doesn't the definition of `gen` suffer from MVP?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Only if `rd` is a typename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
group.dis = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0,19);
```

or

```
group.dis.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type(0,19));
```

Another way would be to add a method to your struct

```
struct group_s {
    int k;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis;
    void set(int a, int b) { dis = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(a,b); }
} group;


group.set(0,19);
```

Comment: Or use a non static data member initializer `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, 19};`

Comment: @Praetorian It's kinda hard to use `std::uniform_int_distribution` before C++11 :)

Comment: @T.C. Hehe. There's `tr1/random` but IIRC it was called something slightly different then.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `uniform_int_distribution` has a move constructor?

Comment: But that means this answer is incorrect, no?  @eswaat

Comment: @Yakk Answer edit to use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type`

Comment: @Yakk Distributions are guaranteed CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable. ([rand.req.dist]/p4)

Comment: @t.c. thanks, that was what I was asking: I did not know.  Docs at cppreference is lacking looks like

Answer (score 6):

Use `param()`:

```
using param_t = std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type;

group.dis.param(param_t(0, 19));
```

If the parameters change every time you use the distribution, then you can also consider using the two-parameter overload of `operator()` instead:

```
std::cout << group.dis(gen, param_t(0, 19)) << ' ';
```

As distribution objects are allowed to store extra bits of entropy obtained during a previous `operator()` call, this approach can be more efficient than constructing a new distribution object and assigning it.

Note that the cppreference page is incomplete and doesn't document the requirements the standard imposes on `param_type`. Given a distribution type `D` and its associated `param_type` `P`,

> For each of the constructors of `D` taking arguments corresponding to
>   parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding
>   constructor subject to the same requirements and taking arguments
>   identical in number, type, and default values. Moreover, for each of
>   the member functions of `D` that return values corresponding to
>   parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding member
>   function with the identical name, type, and semantics.

(§26.5.1.6 [rand.req.dist]/p9)

Comment: I am curious, why `group.dis.param({0, 19});` doesn't seem to work.  Bug?  `std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0,2}` seems to work.

Comment: @Yakk Presumably the constructor is `explicit`, like `std::uniform_int_distribution`'s constructor taking two integers.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
group.dis = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0,19);
```

instead of

```
group.dis(0,19);
```

Also, your code seems to be taken without reference directly from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), so a link as kind of a tributal citation would have been in order.

Comment: a quick glance at cppreference doesn't show a move constructor guaranteed for `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`.  Do you have evidence to the contrary?