# Generate random integers in changing intervals

Tags: c++, random

We can use `std::uniform_int_distribution` to generate random numbers in a specific interval. However, for my simulation I need a uniformly distributed random integer at each iteration, and the interval is dependent on the outcome of the previous iteration. I'm already aware of some of the tricks [(like these)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-number-from-within-a-range) that can be used to produce a uniform / near-uniform distribution of integers from a larger interval, but is there a standard or recommended "post-c++11ish" way to do this?

I know it's possible to just create a new `uniform_int_distribution` object at each iteration. Are there any hidden caveats or gotchas to this approach? It seems that distribution objects do hold some internal state, so I'm slightly concerned that using a fresh distribution object to generate a single random number might have some drawbacks or undesirable characteristics that are not obvious to me.

Comment: I don't know if there is any overhead for creating a new distribution. You can change bounds of existing distribution though, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28328983/12463032

Comment: @TedLyngmo - your comment would work as an answer if you want to do that - I'd completely missed the overload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `uniform_int_distribution` is supposed to be cheap to create but if you are concerned you can supply temporary distribution parameters when calling it using the overload:

[`result_type operator()( Generator& g, const param_type& params );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator())